# Small sample database for practicing database administration?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-recommendation

I'm looking for a portable sample database that

- can be created from a script
- has a simple ER model
- has little data for database administration practicing purposes.

I know that there is e.g. Adventureworks, Northwind and pubs sample databases out there, but I'm looking for something smaller.

Any idea where I can find this kind of database?

Comment: Why smaller??  All of those databases you listed can be scripted and easily ported.

Comment: Smaller ER model, more easily adopted.

Comment: Smaller than pubs? It only has 10 tables with 20s of rows in each. Any smaller is too trivial and worthless for learning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the [Dell DVD Store database](http://linux.dell.com/dvdstore/). It's available for multiple databases, SQL Server included.

> The Dell DVD Store is an open source simulation of an online ecommerce
>   site with implementations in Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL and
>   PostgreSQL along with driver programs and web applications

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Adventureworks database is already setup with flaws that provide good practice.</strike>

There is also a BI database offered as well by MS, search for "Contoso BI demo". This database is only offered as a backup file which provides you practice for one vital task that every DBA should know: restore.

There are a ton of data sets on the world wide web that offer practice on building your own "small" database. I am doing this now to practice design, scripting, and working with SSRS.

Comment: What flaws does AdventureWorks have?

Comment: maybe not flaws necessarily but improvements could be made, guess indexes and such

Answer (score 1):

You can't find more [small ones](http://www.sqlbooks.ru/scripts.aspx?lang=eng). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the AdventureWorks and AdventureWorks2008 databases which have about 600 objects, there are a couple of smaller MS sample databases: AdventureWorksDW, AdventureWorksDW2008, AdventureWorksLT, AdventureWorksDW2008, each one contains about 150 objects

You can download them here: http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use the official sample databases from MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html.